# Setting paths in python

Tags: python, path, pygame, relative-path

I currently have a .py file which aims to drag images out of a folder which is in a folder in the same directory as the .py file. I've set the current directory, however cannot access the images using a relative path.

```
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\alesi\\Documents\\Pygame\\Project\\') #current folder change

win = display.set_mode((640, 640))#load window
Clock = time.Clock() #handy clock

background = image.load('trees.png').convert()#load images

for I in range(0,8):
    walk[I] = sprite('\\png\\cat\\walk (' + str(I) + ').png', 0, 450)
```

Haven't had much experience manipulating the directory in python, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use a leading `.` to indicate relative position. Forward slashes should also work just fine because python does auto conversion for you.

```
os.chdir('C:/Users/alesi/Documents/Pygame/Project/') #current folder change

win = display.set_mode((640, 640))#load window
Clock = time.Clock() #handy clock

background = image.load('trees.png').convert()#load images

for I in range(0,8):
    walk[I] = sprite('./png/cat/walk (' + str(I) + ').png', 0, 450)
```

Technically `walk[I] = sprite('png/cat/walk (' + str(I) + ').png', 0, 450)` would work as well. The problem is your preceding slash making the relative path confused. If you want the preceding slash, use the `.` but if you don't just get rid of the slash and you're golden.